# Respond to inbound connections from multiple gateways on a single interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing, gateway, netplan

I have a network with multiple gateways (`gw1`: `10.0.0.1` and `gw2`: `11.0.0.1`).

My server (Ubuntu 20.04) have one NIC with multiple addresses (`eth0:gw1`: `10.0.0.55` and `eth0:gw2`: `11.0.0.55`).

Each gateway provide internet access and have a NAT rule configured to forward ports `80` and `443` to my server.

In my server I've configured nginx to respond to both address and from internal network it works like I've expected.

---

The problem is: it doesn't respond at calls coming from both public IPs (connection timeout) but only to those coming from the default gateway.

Following the [Netplan documentation](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/) I tried dozens of configurations but I couldn't get responses from both public IPs, always only from the default one (they both work, I tried swapping them and only using them one at a time to confirm).

I'm not a network engineer so I don't know if is a thing possible to do or not.
Is it possible?

---

My actual netplan config:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.55/24:
            label: "eth0:gw1"
        - 11.0.0.55/24:
            label: "eth0:gw2"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.1
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.1
          metric: 200
          table: 101
        - to: default
          via: 11.0.0.1
          metric: 200
          table: 102
      routing-policy:
        - to: 10.0.0.0/24
          from: 10.0.0.0/24
          table: 101
        - to: 11.0.0.0/24
          from: 11.0.0.0/24
          table: 102
```

I don't know if I need more or less options in my config (ex: `routing-policy`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your policy rules are incorrect. You have:

```
      routing-policy:
        - to: 10.0.0.0/24
          from: 10.0.0.0/24
          table: 101
        - to: 11.0.0.0/24
          from: 11.0.0.0/24
          table: 102
```

But for a request coming from *outside* of your local network, the source address will *not* be from `10.0.0.0/24`; it will be the address of a remote client somewhere on the internet. In a typical configuration, your gateways will not masquerade *inbound* traffic; they only masquerade *outbound* traffic so that replies appear to originate at the gateway rather than from the internal server.

That means your `to: ...` rules are never going to match. You should only match using `from: ...` (which is the source address for the reply from your server at `x.0.0.55/24`).

I think you need:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      optional: true
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.55/24:
            label: "eth0:gw1"
        - 11.0.0.55/24:
            label: "eth0:gw2"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.1
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.1
          metric: 200
          table: 101
        - to: default
          via: 11.0.0.1
          metric: 200
          table: 102
      routing-policy:
        - from: 10.0.0.0/24
          table: 101
        - from: 11.0.0.0/24
          table: 102
```

Comment: You can see my test environment [here](https://github.com/larsks/sf-example-1130038-two-gateways), which uses [mininet](http://mininet.org/) to create a virtual network topology. The example uses manual configuration rather than netplan.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly!